Script works well when directly ran but not as startup app
I've made a script for helping me to automatically open some softwares I use for defined kinds of work, which name is Profile Chooser. For example, I have a profile on Firefox and one in Brave for studying translation and other two for studying programming, among other apps, and want to open all of them at once when I log in in Xubuntu, my OS.
Observation 1: I've written such script so I don't want to let everything open all the time nor hibernation (I refer to the option similiar the hibernation of Windows, in which one can turn the machine completely off) works on my Aspire E5-571, even though it works on my Windows 10 installation.
Observation 2: I don't want to create one more user profile in the OS.
This is the output of the screen of the script.
--------------------
|  Profile Chooser |
--------------------

Hello! What do you want to work with today?

  1. Programming
  2. Translation

Type the number of the profile you want to choose or something else for quitting:
> 


The directory of the script have these structure:

The very script: profile_chooser.sh;
The icon: profile-chooser.png;
The directory profile, which have the very profiles, which actually initializes the programs and are read by profile_chooser.sh.

Below is profile_chooser.sh:
#!/bin/bash

# Determine the directory of the script
SCRIPT_DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"

# Set the profiles directory relative to the script directory
PROFILES_DIR="$SCRIPT_DIR/profiles"

# Check if profiles directory exists
if [ ! -d "$PROFILES_DIR" ]; then
  echo "Profiles directory not found!"
  exit 1
fi

# Function to extract the slug from a script
get_slug() {
  local script=$1
  grep '^# slug:' "$script" | cut -d'"' -f2
}

# List all scripts in the profiles directory and get their slugs
profiles=()
for script in "$PROFILES_DIR"/*.sh; do
  slug=$(get_slug "$script")
  if [ -n "$slug" ]; then
    profiles+=("$slug:$script")
  fi
done

# Sort profiles alphabetically by slug
IFS=$'\n' sorted_profiles=($(sort <<<"${profiles[*]}"))
unset IFS

# Display the menu
echo -e "--------------------\n|  Profile Chooser |\n--------------------\n\nHello! What do you want to work with today?\n"
for i in "${!sorted_profiles[@]}"; do
  slug=$(echo "${sorted_profiles[$i]}" | cut -d':' -f1)
  echo "  $((i+1)). $slug"
done

# Prompt user for input
read -p $'\nType the number of the profile you want to choose or something else for quitting:\n> ' choice

# Validate input and run the selected profile
if [[ "$choice" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && [ "$choice" -ge 1 ] && [ "$choice" -le "${#sorted_profiles[@]}" ]; then
  selected_profile=$(echo "${sorted_profiles[$((choice-1))]}" | cut -d':' -f2)
  echo "Starting profile: $(get_slug "$selected_profile")"
  # Make the terminal full screen (Linux specific, may vary based on terminal)
  printf '\e[9;1t'
  # Run the selected profile script
  bash "$selected_profile"
else
  echo -e "\nQuitting..."
  sleep 1
  exit 0
fi

Below is an example of profile. Note it has a slug, which appears in the main menu of the Profile Chooser.
#!/bin/bash
# slug: "Translation"

# Open Firefox browser with the Translation profile
nohup firefox -P "Translation" &

# Open the translation project directory with VS Code
nohup code ~/Repos/Volunteering/MDN/pt-BR/translated-content/ &

# Open Brave browser with the Profile 1 profile
nohup brave-browser --profile-directory="Profile 1" &

I've made an alias: alias profile-chooser="/home/user/Shell\ Scripts/profile-chooser/profile_chooser.sh && exit". That works well. I've put exit here because the terminal was not being automatically closed after the opening the the programs when the exit  in the end of the scripts of each profile or after the line of bash "$selected_profile"; another problem I have not solved.
I've tried to run the script at session login in these ways:

By calling profile_chooser.sh directly. Nothing appeared to happen when I logged in.
By using this command: xfce4-terminal --title="Profile Chooser" --fullscreen --hide-menubar --zoom=2 --command="bash /home/user/profile-chooser/profile_chooser.sh". In this manner, the menu shows up, but nothing happens when I choose a profile. I've tried to make it work by putting the full path the programs in the scripts of the profiles; example: nohup /snap/bin/firefox -P "Translation" &. Same problem: menu functioning, programs not opening. Also, I've created a .desktop file for launching the script and it had the same problem described in this paragraph.
I have also given 777 permissions to the .desktop files in ~/.local/share/applications and ~/.config/autostart.

Could someone help me? I want to learn with this failures of mine with these script and it would also be handy to have my scripts running at startup.

Either nothing happens or the process terminates when the terminal exits. Please verify which is which. Maybe you can ask for user input before exiting the terminal to see.

What exactly do you mean by session login?

The normal way to debug this would be to a) add set -x after the #!/bin/bash and check whether all the variables have the expected content in the failure scenarios ...

@konsolebox, it solved my problem, now the apps run.  Otherwise this folowing snippet is printed during debugging (thanks, @tink), it appears the tasks weren't being actually executed, since no app opened.
+ nohup firefox -P Translation
+ nohup code ~/repo
+ nohup brave-browser '--profile-directory=Profile 1'

now the user must manually hit Enter for closing the terminal. Would be there a way for closing the terminal autiomaticaly?
P.s.: @user1934428, by "session login" I meant the act of logging in when you start the OS.

@jhiuzak What solved your problem? Did you add a command to ask for input before exiting? What was the command you added? Also asking for input was not meant to be a solution but a diagnosis. You are meant to identify if the processes exit when the terminal terminates. Did you identify it? If it's "working" now after you ask for input, did you find out why it is?
